# Changing a Function into a synchronous execution in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have looked through this example code:

```
function findItem() {
    var item;
    while(item_not_found) {
        // search
    }
    return item;
}

var item = findItem();
// do something with item
doSomethingElse();
```

And am trying to get my google chrome extension's code to be in the same format (synchronous).

So far I have

```
var token = chrome.storage.local.get('token', function (result) {
  var tokens = result.token;
  alert("IN: " + tokens);
  return tokens;
});
alert(token);
```

But, this doesn't work. It never prints the alert in the function at all, and the print that does appear says that token is undefined.

This asynchronous code worked:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('token', function (result) {
  var tokens = result.token;
});
```

But I need to get that value of tokens first, then move on with the other code.

Comment: You don't. You cannot convert an async function to synchronous execution, but you can change the synchronous call into an asynchronous one.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't fully understand what that would look like. I am open to a different approach that achieves the same ends.

Comment: Just put the code that depends on the value into the callback. There are tons of googlable examples of how to organize asynchronous code execution in javascript.

Comment: Use Promises. They make async code *feel* like synchronous code even though it isn't. Or if you truly need more look at ES6/2015 generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a lack of understanding about *asynchronous* code. The return value really has nothing to do with your example. Based on your description of `token` being undefined then the `.get()` method ignores the return value of its callback.

In fact that is the essence of callbacks. The propose of `chrome.storage.local.get()` is to make the value (in this case `result`) available only inside the callback function not outside it. The reason for this is that the act of `.get()` is to do something in the background while your code continues on. It does not wait for anything and so by the time `alert()` is called the `token` variable is assigned the return value of `.get()` which is undefined.

There is no way to break this down without callbacks. Instead put your code inside the callback (see [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) on why this could be a problem).

As an aside you can make this cleaner by using [promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/):

```
function promisedToken() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('token', resolve);
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    var tokens = result.token;
    alert("IN: " + tokens);
    return tokens;
  });
}

promisedToken()
  .then(function(token) {
    alert(token);
  });
```

For more on callbacks: https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks

**Update:** Based on the comment I think what your looking for is some guidance on coding style/architecture. Since this is a chrome extension we know the [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are supported.

There is a library to provide a promise API to `chrome.storage.local`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-storage-promise

For clarity it can be done manually with:

In your case make a generic function that returns a promise:

```
function promisedGet(key) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.store.local.get(key, function(result) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
        reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      } else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then in your code a it is a simple matter of:

```
var promisedResults = promisedGet('token');
var promisedTokens = promisedResults.then(function(result) {
  return result.tokens;
});
promisedTokens.then(function(tokens) {
  alert(tokens);
  return tokens;
});
```

Which can easily be simplified:

```
promisedGet('token')
  .then(function(results) {
    alert(results.tokens);
    return results.tokens;
  });
```

You can make any number of chained results or functions fit for a purpose. The key difference is that any code that needs the result is executed inside a `.then()` function. If any of those throw an error then the error logic goes in a `.catch()` function. This style of programming is very expressive and composable.

Comment: Thanks, but, Is there some way to return a value to a variable then have all code after that execute without putting all the "after that" code inside of promisedToken()?

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense in the context of async code nor with promises. I think you need to take a little time and research how callbacks and promises work. It is obvious you like the return/throw control flow of synchronous code and that is a good thing. Promises are a way to *simulate* the return/throw control flow but with async code. It does however look a little different. [This blog post section](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/#what-is-the-point-of-promises?) speaks to what you want.

Comment: Added some more prose concerning your specific situation.